# Delete the first word and everything after third comma - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I have a line like this:

```
aaaaaaa, bbbbbbb, ccccccc, ddddddd
```

And I need to cut it to look like this:

```
bbbbbbb, ccccccc
```

So how to delete the first word and everything after third comma ?

Comment: `str.split()` is ***not*** deprecated. The old `string` module functions are, because we now have proper methods.

Comment: Also, what's your definition of the first word? Everything up to, and including, the first comma and the spaces immediately following the comma?

Comment: What is `line` ? A string? A list? A line from a file?

Comment: Are all the strings just like that? (use `str.split()`) Or might have some complexity like quoted fields? (use the `csv` module)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, sorry maybe sounds dummy but could you then explain please why it's in section Deprecated (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#7.1.6. Deprecated string functions) and not deprecated?

Comment: @Elena: because those are **functions**. See the [*String Methods* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) for the (newer) string **methods**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple of tricks you could use to achieve what you want:

1. Use .split(', ') to break your line into an array of words
2. Use the sub-array notation ([1:3] for example) to keep the second and third words
3. Reconstruct the array back into a line using .join, supplying any delimiter you'd like (e.g. a new comma)

For example:

```
', '.join("aaa, bbb, ccc, dddd, eeee".split(', ')[1:3])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def wordsTwoAndThree( csvString, sep ): 
    return sep.join(csvString.split(sep)[1:3])

print( wordsTwoAndThree("aaaaaaa, bbbbbbb, ccccccc, ddddddd", ',') )
```

Similarly to @Paedolos 's suggestion.